# Free Module $R^{n}$ with zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Artin's Algebra he says that $R^{n}$, where $R$ is a ring, is a free $R$ module.   But if $R$ contains zero divisors then how can $R$ be free since 
there exists $r,r_{1}$ such that $rr_{1}=0$ with $r,r_{1} \ne 0$ ?

Comment: Why do you think there should be no torsion elements in a free module (over a ring with zero divisors)? The axioms for a free module are clearly satisfied by $R^n$.

Comment: What is your definition of a free module?

Comment: I think the OP has a genuine conceptual problem here, and there is no reason for a down vote. Downvoting without giving a reason discourages people from asking questions.

Comment: I agree with Rankeya. Sometimes I think our intuition comes from domains (like $\mathbf{Z}$ or $K[X]$), and it might seem strange initially that a free module can have ``torsion."

Comment: it was my first day looking at modules.   so im still getting used to the definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (left) module $M$ over a ring $R$ is free if there exists a set $\{m_i:i\in I\}\subseteq M$ such that every element of $M$ can be uniquely written as a sum $\sum_ir_im_i$ with $r_i=0$ for all but finitely many $i$. Applying this to the $R$-module $R$ and the set consisting of the identity element $1\in R$, we see that $R$ is free as a module over itself. Similarly, for $M=R^n$, the elements $e_i=(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$ (with the $1$ in the $i$-th spot) clearly satisfy this condition).

It doesn't matter that $R$ may have zero-divisors. What is true is that if $r\in R$ is a zero divisor, then the set $\{r\}$ does not satisfy the conditions above (it is not a basis for the $R$-module $R$) because $0$ can be written as $0\cdot r$ and $r^\prime\cdot r$ for some non-zero $r^\prime$ (since this is what it means to be a zero-divisor).

I think you might be mixing the notion of a free module with the notion of a torsion-free module; but the latter notion sort of only makes sense for $R$ a domain (then the set of torsion elements of an $R$-module is a submodule). What is true is that a free module over a domain is also torsion-free.

For example, the ring $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ is free as a module over itself (as I pointed out above, the element $1+4\mathbf{Z}$ constitutes a free generating set, or basis), even though it has a zero divisor. Note however that as a $\mathbf{Z}$-module, $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ is not free. In fact it is a torsion $\mathbf{Z}$-module.