Projective implies torsion free
It says on this Wikipedia page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_module
that a free module over a ring $R$ is torsion-free. But if $R$ has zero divisors, then the the rank one free module $R$ cannot be torsion free. What am I misinterpreting in the Wikipedia page.

Very much related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403512 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947186/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241366 but not enough for a duplicate it seems.

For rings with zero divisors, the usual definition of a torsion-free module is one where no nonzero element is annihilated by a non-zero-divisor.
The first paragraph of the Wikipedia page you link to confirms that this is the definition they are using.

It is good practice to avoid unnecessary negations... erm... try to strive for positive statements. This makes life much easier in the end. This is one of the lessons of constructive mathematics. Let me explain how that applies here and thereby also give definitions which are as concise as possible.
We start with the notion of a left regular element in a ring $R$. It is an element $r \in R$ such that $R \to R$, $x \to rx$ is injective. Which is to say that
$$rx = ry \implies x = y.$$
So we can cancel $r$ from the left. Notice that this is a positive statement, no negation appears here. The notion of a right regular element is defined in the same way, here $r$ can be cancelled from the right. An element is regular when it is left regular and right regular. In the commutative case, these three notions coincide.
When you open the wikipedia page for regular elements, you will find the following "definition":

a nonzero element of a ring that is neither a left nor a right zero divisor

and you are directed to the page on zero divisors.

The nonzero assumption is wrong and misleading. Wrong because the zero element in the zero ring is regular. Misleading because the zero element does not need any special consideration. The definition above implies that $0$ is left/right regular iff $R=0$.
The double negation makes this notion complicated without any advantage.
We should do it the other way round: A left zero divisor is defined as an element which is not left regular. Same with right etc. Likewise, we can define a domain to be a non-trivial commutative ring such that every non-zero element is regular.

Regular elements behave much better than zero divisors. Just to give a simple example: the set of regular elements is multiplicatively closed. Notice that every invertible element is regular (since bijective maps are injective).
When $R$ is an integral domain, the regular elements are precisely the non-zero elements. But the general notion of a regular element has absolutely nothing to do with "non-zero". In the same vein, notice that many statements about "non-zero elements of a field" can actually be replaced with statements about "invertible elements of a commutative ring" and often then indeed hold in much greater generality.
Now back to modules. We define a left $R$-module $M$ to be torsionfree when for every left regular element $r \in R$ the map $M \to M$, $m \to rm$ is injective.
Notice that again this is a positive statement. The assumption that $r$ is left regular is essential because otherwise $M=R$ would not be torsionfree. But because of that assumption, $R$ is indeed torsionfree. Also, it follows easily that torsionfree modules are closed under all direct sums and direct products (since injective maps are closed under these operations). It follows that every free left $R$-module is also torsionfree.
Direct summands of torsionfree modules are also torsionfree (since retracts of injective maps are again injective). It follows that every projective left $R$-module is torsionfree.
Notice that all this holds without any assumption on the ring $R$, and in fact it could also be just a semiring.
An element $m \in M$ is called torsion when $rm=0$ for some regular element $r \in R$. The torsion elements form a submodule when $R$ is commutative. Notice that (here we first need that $R$ is a ring, not just a semiring) $M$ is torsionfree iff $0$ is the only torsion element. And there is no need to define torsionfree as "there are no non-zero torsion elements" (again, negation without any gain).
